# The uniqueness principle for products in the HoTT Book

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

This is about a point I do not understand in Section 1.5 of the [HoTT Book](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/). Here is the relevant excerpt:

---

To be able to define *dependent* functions over the product type, we have to generalize the recursor. Given $C:A\times B\to\mathcal U$, we may define a function 
$$
f:\prod_{(x:A\times B)}C(x)
$$
by providing a function
$$
g:\prod_{(x:A)}\prod_{(y:B)}C((x,y))
$$
with defining equation
$$
f((x,y)):\equiv g(x)(y).
$$
For example, in this way we can prove the propositional uniqueness principle, which says that every element of $A\times B$ is equal to a pair. Specifically, we can construct a function
$$
\operatorname{uniq}_{A\times B}:\prod_{x:A\times B}\Big(\big(\operatorname{pr_1}(x),\operatorname{pr_2}(x)\big)=_{A\times B}x\Big).
$$
Here we are using the identity type, which we are going to introduce below in $\S$1.12. However, all we need to know now is that there is a reflexivity element 
$$
\operatorname{refl}_x:x=_Ax
$$ 
for any $x:A$. Given this, we can define
$$
\operatorname{uniq}_{A\times B}((a,b)):\equiv\operatorname{refl}_{(a,b)}.\tag{1}
$$
This construction works, because in the case that $x:\equiv(a,b)$ we can calculate 
$$
\Big(\operatorname{pr_1}\big((a,b)\big),\operatorname{pr_2}\big((a,b)\big)\Big)\equiv(a,b)
$$
using the defining equations for the projections. Therefore,
$$
\operatorname{refl}_{(a,b)}:\Big(\operatorname{pr_1}\big((a,b)\big),\operatorname{pr_2}\big((a,b)\big)\Big)=(a,b)
$$
is well-typed, since both sides of the equality are judgmentally equal.

---

The whole section is available at http://planetmath.org/15producttypes. The whole book is available at http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/. (To find the above paragraph in the section or in the book, you can search for the chain of characters "works, because".)

I think I see why the judgmental equality 
$$
\Big(\operatorname{pr_1}\big((a,b)\big),\operatorname{pr_2}\big((a,b)\big)\Big)\equiv(a,b)
$$ 
holds for all $a:A$ and all $b:B$. The authors seem to say that this implies that the judgmental equality 
$$
\big(\operatorname{pr_1}(x),\operatorname{pr_2}(x)\big)\equiv x
$$ 
holds for all $x:A\times B$. I do not understand why.

Instead of $(1)$ I would have expected 
$$
\operatorname{uniq}_{A\times B}(x):\equiv\operatorname{refl}_x,\tag{2}
$$ 
but even with $(1)$ replaced by $(2)$ my non understanding remains.

Comment: I would not say that the judgemental equality for $x$ follows from the judgemental equality for $(a, b)$, but certainly the _propositional_ equality follows.

Comment: Your comment confirms the fact that I don't understand the point! Could you spell out the reason why the propositional equality for $x$ follows from the judgemental equality for $(a,b)$? (When I posted the question, I told myself: "the best thing that could happen would be that @ZhenLin answers it". I'm delighted!)

Comment: It has to do with the induction principle for products.

Comment: @ZhenLin - Thanks! But my non understanding of HoTT is such that I need a detailed explanation rather than a hint...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have copied out the induction principle for products.  We are now applying that principle with the type family $C(x) :\equiv (((\mathsf{pr}_1(x),\mathsf{pr}_2(x))=x)$.  The desired function $f$ will be our proof that $((\mathsf{pr}_1(x),\mathsf{pr}_2(x))=x)$ for all $x:A\times B$.  The induction principle says that to obtain $f$, it suffices to give $g$, which means to show that $((\mathsf{pr}_1((a,b)),\mathsf{pr}_2((a,b)))=(a,b))$ for all $a:A$ and $b:B$.  But in *this* case, the two sides are judgmentally equal, so we can define $g(a,b):\equiv \mathsf{refl}_{(a,b)}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a clear answer!!!